# How do I properly organize JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript

I have a massive collection of methods that I want to shape into a library. How do I begin the process?

Here is the begnning of the consolidation effort: I'm trying to decide if I should do this for my whole code base — move similar items into JavaScript objects.

Below is the consolidation effort followed by the whole code base:

Should I shape my code this way?

#### Consolidation Effort:

```
var menu = {   

  menu_timer:0,
  menu_element:0,

  /* called when mousing over the top menu item */

  top_mouse_over: function (id) 
    {
    menu.bottom_mouse_over();
    menu.menu_element=document.getElementById(id);
    menu.menu_element.style.visibility='visible';
    },

  /* hide the menu when the timer runs out */

  hide_menu: function()
    {
    if(menu.menu_element)menu.menu_element.style.visibility='hidden';
    },

  /* keeps the menu open by clearing the timer when mousing over the menu items */

  bottom_mouse_over: function() 
    {
    if(menu.menu_timer)
      {
      window.clearTimeout(menu.menu_timer);}
    },

  /* set the timer to hide the menu, required by clearTimeout */

  mouse_out: function() 
    {
    menu.menu_timer=window.setTimeout(menu.hide_menu, 1000);
    }

};
```

#### Entire Code Base:

Moved to codereview

Comment: You might try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - SO is for more specific programming questions.

Comment: Don't minify in the source, minify as part of the build/deploy process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new approach is certainly an improvement. You should feel free to have your own style, but I would consider taking a conventional approach around [documentation generation](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/w/list). In addition, if you take advantage of a library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/), you'll be able to adapt from their style, instead of inventing your own. (I promise it won't stifle your creativity.)

Finally, you may consider pseudo-namespacing your object with a name that's less likely to be overridden in global. "window.menu" strikes me as slightly dangerous. *Brand* your core object while you namespace it.

Answer (score 4):

First, refactor.

There no reason for a function called `16` or `m6`.

A few suggestions:

- Use jQuery, Dojo, Zepto or any other library for your AJAX calls and mouse/keyboard events. There's no reason to reinvent the wheel. You now need to test your AJAX functions on every browser in the world. jQuery's AJAX function has already been tested.
- try to use [prettyDate](http://ejohn.org/files/pretty.js) instead of `view_date`.
- Why do you minimize function names? What's the reason? Compressors can do this for you. Seriously, how can you work with this:

  function m2(a,b) {
      return document.getElementById(a).innerHTML=b;
    }
- Look into template functions (such as _.template, jQuery.template, mustache, etc). Look into validation plugins that might make your work easier.
- You have 800 lines of code. You can make this to 200 **readable** lines of code.
- Regarding making it a library: depending on the context I usually make it a jQuery plugin or using _.extend. Namespacing it to `var menu = {}` is sufficient though I'd pick a more relevant name than menu.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on Paul Irish's (Google Chrome, jQuery) method of kick-starting page-specific code.

http://paulirish.com/2009/markup-based-unobtrusive-comprehensive-dom-ready-execution/

Comment: very fancy...but no need

Comment: While the method is intended for initializing code it is also very convenient way to organize code; so don't dismiss the idea because it isn't exactly what you are looking for.